# Relative position along path

Tags: path, position, raphael, bezier

I have a shape that moves along an open path and I'm wondering how could I get it's relative position, i.e. given the (x,y) coordinate of the shape and the length (L) of the path (p), the function should return the ratio (r) where the point is located.

For example, r = 0 would mean the point is at the very beginning of the path, 0.25 at the quarter, 0.5 half, etc.

One way I could do it would be to iterate over the function p.getPointAtLength() for different length increments until the given position is within an acceptable range from my original point (x, y). And then simply divide this value by p.getTotalLength().

But is there a more efficient and precise way to do it knowing that in my case the path is a 4 point bézier curve ?

Comment: How are you positioning the shape, wouldn't you already know this as you've had to calculate how far along the path it is, to get the x,y to position it ?

Comment: Yes I set initial position of the shape at half the curve, but if it's dragged away well here comes the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Reparameterising a Bezier curve for distance, rather than time, is a non-trivial problem without a general solution, so by far the most efficient way to do this for "moving along a path on a computer screen" is a LUT-based approach like http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be interested, here's how I worked it around :

```
getLengthAtPoint = function(x, y, curve){
  var len = curve.getTotalLength(),
    tol = len/100,
    inc = len/100,
    err,
    errMin = 99999, // infinity
    cond = true,
    lengthIter = 0,
    lengthMin = 0;

  do {
    err = dist(curve.getPointAtLength(lengthIter), {x, y}); //pythagore
    cond = err>tol;
    if (err < errMin){
      errMin = err;
      lengthMin = lengthIter;
    }
    lengthIter = lengthIter + inc;
    if (lengthIter > len) {cond = false;}
  } while (cond);

  return (lengthMin/len);
}
```